# Disable autofill form inputs in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Any one have an idea how to disable auto fill in chrome

I have used for sure `$("#my_input").val()` it works fine with `Firefox` but not `Chrome`

I have used `jquery` `$("#form").disableAutoFill()` `autocomplete="off"`

any suggestions

Not just removing from the input , i want aswell `no suggestions` from chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Comment: @gforce301 it's not solved and i have done the same by theway

Comment: The answer to "Disabling Chrome Autofill" quetion has a lot of info, I suggest looking there, but try this as a first step `autocomplete="false"`

Comment: I have checked, nothing works and triedthis aswell unfortunately doesn't work, why not open the question again

Answer (score 0):

To disable Chrome autofill and suggestions in items which have a valid autofill value such as name or email, add autocomplete="nope".

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="nope" name="email">
```

In cases where you have previously saved values that are showing dropdown suggestions, for example in a column of numbers in an accounting page, use JS to change the names of the inputs.

```
<input type="text" data-name="my_inputname">
```

An example of how you would do this with jQuery:
https://codepen.io/btn-ninja/pen/EBmNQb

In cases where you want the autocomplete to work, here is documentation on valid autocomplete values:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete